# Remove several array elements by index and store removed elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I remove multiple items by index and save the removed items. I get the currently selected values from a ListBox (e.g.`selectedValues = [1, 4, 2]`) and have two arrays `actives` `availables`. I try to move the selected elements in an efficient way.

That's how I would solve this:

```js
var actives = [ "a", "d", "k", "e"]
var availables = [ "m", "o", "v" ]
var selectedValues = [3, 1]
var elementsToMove = []

selectedValues.forEach(i => {
  elementsToMove.push(actives[i])
})

actives = actives.filter(item => !elementsToMove.includes(item))
availables = availables.concat(elementsToMove);

console.log(actives);
console.log(availables);
```

**Expected output:**

```
actives = [ "a", "k" ]
availables = [ "m", "o", "v", "e", "d"]
```

**Note:** The length of the arrays can be very large.

Comment: Can you illustrate your issue with example data? How should the arrays look like afterwards

Comment: You can take the sample data from my code snippet.

The arrays should look like this:
   ```actives = [ "a", "k"]```
   ```availables = ["m", "o", "v", "e", "d"]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.filter` with an `.includes` inside is `O(n ^ 2)`. For very large inputs, this could be an issue. Consider converting the `elementsToMove` into a Set instead, turning the overall computational complexity to `O(n)`. You can also construct the `elementsToMove` array much more concisely by using `.map` instead of `forEach` followed by `push`:

```js
var actives = [ "a", "d", "k", "e"]
var availables = [ "m", "o", "v" ]
var selectedValues = [3, 1];
const elementsToMove = selectedValues.map(i => actives[i]);
const elementsToMoveSet = new Set(elementsToMove);

actives = actives.filter(item => !elementsToMoveSet.has(item))
availables = availables.concat(elementsToMove);

console.log(actives);
console.log(availables);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and psuh the spliced elements to the other array.

```js
var actives = [ "a", "d", "k", "e"],
    availables = [ "m", "o", "v" ],
    selectedValues = [3, 1];

selectedValues.forEach(i => availables.push(...actives.splice(i, 1)));

console.log(actives);
console.log(availables);
```